# How to change mega menu name dynamicaly in drupal 7.x?

Tags: drupal, authentication, logout, megamenu

I have used [TB mega menu]:https://www.drupal.org/node/2512826
and create a menu 'login', now when user is login want to change the name as logout, can it possible please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MultiBlock](https://www.drupal.org/project/multiblock) Drupal module for this.
You'll need to create new instance of the block you have with another title and also apply roles rules for both blocks.